# Latexmk: Automatic creation of aux and output directories seems not working

Tags: latexmk

A function of latexmk, automatic creation of aux and output directories seems not working in my environment.

Here is the minimal example that simulates the error.

```
parent-folder
 - main.tex
 - sub-folder
    - sub.tex

[main.tex]
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}
A minimal example.
\include{sub-folder/sub}
\end{document}

[sub.tex]
    texts to be included

[.latexmkrc]
$max_repeat   = 5;
$pdf_mode     = 1;
$aux_dir      = '.build';
$out_dir      = '.';
```

I am using MacBookAir with M2 chip running macOS Sonoma 14.1.1.

Comment: Life is too short to waste it with output and aux folders!

Comment: Which version of latexmk are you using?

Comment: What errors were reported when you ran latexmk?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm using Version 4.81 released on 6 Nov. 2023.

Comment: The error raised is 
```
! I can't write on file `sub-folder/sub.aux'.
\@include ...mmediate \openout \@partaux "#1.aux" 
```

Comment: After the error message, pdf stops at a prompt, and one of the possibilities shown for what to do is to type "Control-D to exit".  Do that.  Then latexmk will create the necessary directory, which here is `.build/sub-folder`.  After that, latexmk will rerun pdflatex (twice, in fact), and there will no longer be an error.  Unfortunately, latexmk does not know to create the subdirectory in `.build` until after the first run of pdflatex, when it can examine the log file for diagnostic information.

Comment: I appreciate the guidance provided in your response. I have a follow-up question regarding the use of the '-interaction=nonstopmode' option. I'm currently using latexmk with LaTeX Workshop on VSCode. Is there a way to achieve the same result without needing to type anything into the prompt? Any further advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One possibility is to configure VSCode to put `-interaction=nonstopmode` on the command line it passes to latexmk.  Another is to put `set_tex_cmds( '-interaction=nonstopmode %O %S' );` in your .latexmkrc file.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help!